# File process calculation by time and amount processed

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am trying to get a good formula to calculate the time left for file processing. In 1 hour 10.3 GB of files can be processed. How many hours would it take to process the 45 GB files?

Comment: The "processing speed" is $10.3$GB per hour. Assuming the amount processed is directly proportional to time taken, then it takes $\frac{45}{10.3}$ hours to process the $45$GB files.

Answer (score 1):

$$45\text{ GB} \times \frac{1\text{ hour}}{10.3\text{ GB}} \;\;\approx\;\; 4.369\text{ hours} $$

Assuming the amount of time it takes to process $n$ GB of files in linear in $n$, then $\frac{1\text{ hour}}{10.3\text{ GB}}$ is our "unit" of converting between GB and hours.